# Magento Order/Invoice PDF is corrupt in 1.9

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

Whenever I click "Print" on a magento invoice or order, the resulting PDF is corrupt and unreadable.

I have searched SO for this answer and there are solutions related to earlier versions of magento with construct / destruct method but this doesn't seem to apply in 1.9 or at least I cannot find where it would apply.

Has anyone else had this issue? I cannot seem to find an answer that applies to 1.9

Comment: I have the same problem.  I've seen some suggestions that it's a bug in the Zend file parser but nothing confirmed.  Did you solve it?

Comment: No I have not yet solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually related to QuirkyFoxLab's Easy JQuery extension. Around line 16 in /app/code/local/Quirkyfoxlabs/EasyJquery/Model/Observer.php there is:

```
//get extension's parameters
    $myParams = Quirkyfoxlabs_Easyjquery_Helper_Data::getExtParams();

    if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() && !Mage::app()->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        $myHtml = $response->getBody();
```

and changing that to:

```
 //get extension's parameters
    $myParams = Quirkyfoxlabs_Easyjquery_Helper_Data::getExtParams();
    if(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() == 'adminhtml')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() && !Mage::app()->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        $myHtml = $response->getBody();
```

Fixed the issue for me. I hope this helps someone else.